# Assigning NULL to the head node in a linked list in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list, reference

Please see the full code below.

I have an initial array named `arr`.
I'm using a linked list to store some indices via the `append` function. After I got the indices, I store them in linked list and use `clearList` to change the corresponding values to 0 (In this example arr[2] and arr[4]). 
Finally, I free the memory by calling `freeList` since i'm done with the linked list.

However, to be able to do same thing again and again, I need to set `head` to NULL whenever I call `freeList`. But I cannot. Any idea how to solve this? 
Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include "gurobi_c.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

//Gurobi variables
GRBenv   *env = NULL;
GRBmodel *model = NULL;
//Gurobi variables

struct Node 
{ 
  int data; 
  struct Node *next;
  struct Node *end;
};

void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) 
    { 
    struct Node *last = *head_ref;  
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  
    new_node->data  = new_data; 
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->end = new_node;
    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
       *head_ref = new_node;
       //printf("  ..Init Append %d\n",new_data);
       return; 
    } 
    last = (*head_ref)->end; 
    last->next = new_node;  
    (*head_ref)->end=new_node;
    //printf("  ..Append %d\n",new_data);
    return; 
} 

void clearList(struct Node *node, double *arr) 
    { 
    int i;
    if(node!=NULL)
        {
        struct Node tmp;
        tmp=*(node->end);
        while (node != NULL) 
            {  
            i=node->data;
            arr[i]=0;
            //printf("   ..clear %d \n", node->data,(node->end)->data);
            node = node->next; 
            }
        }
    }

void freeList(struct Node *node) 
    { 
    struct Node *tmp,*hd;
    hd=node;
    while (node != NULL) 
        { 
        tmp=node;
        node = node->next; 
        //printf("  ..Free %d \n", tmp->data);      
        free(tmp);
        } 
    hd=NULL;
    }

int main (){
    Node *head;     
    double *arr = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        arr[i]=i;

    head=NULL;
    printf("Head:  %s\n", head);
    append(&head,2);
    append(&head,4);
    clearList(head,arr);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("No %d : %.2f\n",i,arr[i]);
    freeList(head);

    free(arr);

    printf("%s", head);
    getchar();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How do you change the value of `head` when appending? Maybe that way could be used for deleting too...

Comment: I do not change the value of head, it always stays the same. I only add new nodes to the list.

Comment: If you never change the value of `head`, it would be `NULL` and your list would be empty...so your `append` function must be changing it somehow

Comment: Correct. I do this by `head_ref` in `append`. However, in `freeList`, I free head ,which complicates the situation.

Comment: If you would pass the address of `head` to `freeList` you could set it to NULL in `freeList`. Otherwise you would have to do `head = NULL;` after calling `clearList`. You could also create a preprocessor macro, e.g. `clearListNull` that does both.

Comment: @Bodo Would you explain how to do that exactly please? My problem is I know that it could be done by manipulating addresses, but cannot make it work.  I kinda find an alternative solution but would like to learn to do it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already changing the value of head in your `append` function so you basically need to do the same thing in `freeList`:

```
void freeList(struct Node **head_ref) 
    { 
    struct Node *tmp,*node;
    node=*head_ref;
    while (node != NULL) 
        { 
        tmp=node;
        node = node->next; 
        //printf("  ..Free %d \n", tmp->data);      
        free(tmp);
        } 
    *head_ref=NULL;
    }

int main (){
    /* do stuff */
    freeList(&head);
    /* do stuff */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: Another possible option would be to use a wrapper macro for `freeList()`.

```
void freeList(struct Node *node) 
{ 
    /* ... */
}

#define freeListNull(node) do { \
    freeList(node); \
    node = NULL; \
} while(0)

int main () {
    /* ... */
    freeListNull(head);
    /* ... */
}
```

This solution has a similar disadvantage as the version that returns the modified pointer. You can simply forget to use the right call `freeListNull(head);` and call `freeList(head);` instead. The best solution is a function `freeList()` that takes the address of the `head` pointer as in idk's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I realized it is possible to change the `freeList` function so that it will return a NULL value. See the updated code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include "gurobi_c.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

//Gurobi variables
GRBenv   *env = NULL;
GRBmodel *model = NULL;
//Gurobi variables

struct Node 
{ 
  int data; 
  struct Node *next;
  struct Node *end;
};

void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) 
    { 
    struct Node *last = *head_ref;  
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  
    new_node->data  = new_data; 
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->end = new_node;
    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
       *head_ref = new_node;
       //printf("  ..Init Append %d\n",new_data);
       return; 
    } 
    last = (*head_ref)->end; 
    last->next = new_node;  
    (*head_ref)->end=new_node;
    //printf("  ..Append %d\n",new_data);
    return; 
} 

void clearList(struct Node *node, double *arr) 
    { 
    int i;
    if(node!=NULL)
        {
        struct Node tmp;
        tmp=*(node->end);
        while (node != NULL) 
            {  
            i=node->data;
            arr[i]=0;
            //printf("   ..clear %d \n", node->data,(node->end)->data);
            node = node->next; 
            }
        }
    }

Node* freeList(struct Node *node) 
    { 
    struct Node *tmp;
    while (node != NULL) 
        { 
        tmp=node;
        node = node->next; 
        printf("  ..Free %d \n", tmp->data);      
        free(tmp);
        } 
    return NULL;
    }

int main (){
    Node *head;     
    double *arr = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        arr[i]=i;

    head=NULL;
    printf("Head:  %s -> null as expected\n", head);
    append(&head,2);
    append(&head,4);
    clearList(head,arr);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("No %d : %.2f\n",i,arr[i]);

    printf("Head:  %s -> Not null as linkedlist is not freed\n", head);
    head=freeList(head);
    printf("Head:  %s -> Again null as expected\n", head);
    free(arr);
    printf("%s", head);
    getchar();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Aside: Why the unneeded cast in `new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node))`?  Consider `new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node)`. `arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * 10);` etc.  instead.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: I think idk's solution is better because nothing prevents you from calling `freeList(head);` or even `(void)freeList(head);` in your code.